# Trying to create timetable programmatically in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, timetable

I can't seem to find a way to create a table in Xamarin C# to look similar to the attached screenshot. The timetable needs to change dynamically according to the user signed in currently. Is there a way to create a table like below and fill it with data?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Cfc.jpg

Comment: GridView? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the response. Would the code in the link be able to be adapted to get strings from an array instead of images?

Comment: GridView is just a layout mechanism.  You can put any kind of content you want inside of it.  There are numerous examples available.